# Convert string to numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, string-literals

I have a string representation of a numpy array of arrays. How do you convert from this format to an array of arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: That's a vague description of your string.  How did you create this string?  You know, don't you, the normal way of creating an array from a list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

Using eval is the best solution

```py
import numpy as np

a = "np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])"

a = eval(a)
```